# Error parsing XML string to XDocument

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have this XML string `bn`:

`<Root><Row><ITEMNO>1</ITEMNO><USED>y</USED><PARTSOURCE>Buy</PARTSOURCE><QTY>2</QTY></Row><Row><ITEMNO>5</ITEMNO><PARTSOURCE>Buy</PARTSOURCE><QTY>5</QTY></Row></Root>`

I am trying to convert it to an `XDocument` like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(bn);
```

However, I get this error:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**

This is the method I use to create the xml string:

```
public static string SerializeObjectToXml(Root rt)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
    var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);

    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, rt);
    memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;

    string xmlString = ByteArrayToStringUtf8(memoryStream.ToArray());

    xmlTextWriter.Close();
    memoryStream.Close();
    memoryStream.Dispose();

    return xmlString;
}
```

It does add  to the start that I have to remove.  Could I change something to make it correct from the start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two characters at the beginning of your string that, although you can't see them, are still there and make the string fail. Try this instead:

```xml
<Root><Row><ITEMNO>1</ITEMNO><USED>y</USED><PARTSOURCE>Buy</PARTSOURCE><QTY>2</QTY></Row><Row><ITEMNO>5</ITEMNO><PARTSOURCE>Buy</PARTSOURCE><QTY>5</QTY></Row></Root>
```

The character in question is [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm). This is a byte-order mark, basically telling the program reading it if it's big or little endian. It seems like you copied and pasted this from a file that wasn't decoded properly.

To remove it, you could use this:

```
yourString.Replace(((char)0xFEFF).ToString(), "")
```

Comment: How do I eliminate it from the string if I can tell it is there?

Comment: @davids Use `.Replace(((char)0xFEFF), '\0');`.

Comment: I was hoping to not have it in their at all, but I don't know why the method is adding it.  I can strip it out as you suggest.

Comment: Now I get: `'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.`.  The string starts with `\0<Root><Row>` after your suggestion

Comment: This solution is unnecessary, particularly given that he's converting to a string first. Please see mine below.

Answer (score 1):

You have two unprintable characters ([Zero-Width No-break Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm)) at the beginning of your string.
XML does not allow text outside the root element.

Comment: These are probably byte-order marks from the Unicode encoding.   That they are still in your document suggests that you haven't explicitly unencoded it, first.   This is a good practice.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that

Comment: How do I unencode it first?  Trying the suggestion from others gives a different error.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does unnecessary `string` processing, but, in its defense, it's because you're unnecessarily dealing in `string` when you don't have to. One of the great things about the .NET XML APIs is that they have robust internals. So instead of trying to feed a `string` to `XDocument.Parse`, feed a `Stream` or some type of `TextReader` to `XDocument.Load`. This way, you aren't fooling with manually managing the encoding and any problems it creates, because the internals will handle all of that stuff for you. Byte-order marks are a pain in the neck, but if you're dealing in XML, .NET makes it easier to handle them.